# The executable file does not find the library if called from the application compiled by Pyinstaller

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller

When running the `mysqlbinlog` process from an application built with `pyinstaller`, the following error message appears:

```
mysqlbinlog: /opt/myapp/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9 'not found (required by mysqlbinlog)
```

I made several tests and noticed that this happens due to the fact that `pyinstaller` puts an older version of the `libz.so.1`, than is needed for `mysqlbinlog`, in the directory where the app is installed. If you delete this file `/opt/myapp/libz.so.1` then the issue will be resolved since the system version of the library is used.

A simple solution would be to remove `libz.so.1` from the bundle, but I'm not sure that after that the application will work correctly on different versions of systems.

Is there any way to force the app not to use the libraries that are located in the directory where the application is installed when running commands via subprocess?

**Additional Information:**

The application is built in the docker container centos:7.2.1511 using the following command:

```
pyinstaller myapp.py --clean --name=myapp
```

This bug is simulated stably on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

mysqlbinlog runs via subprocess, with the following command:

```
subprocess.run(command_args, check = True, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux has an environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH that specifies the directory to search for system libraries. Pyinstaller replaces this variable in such a way that the libraries, needed by the program, are searched in the bundle itself, thus making the work of the application that is compiled by Pyinstaller independent from the system libraries.

At the same time, the old value of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable is saved in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH_ORIG environment variable. Thus, when starting a third-party process, you just need to set the correct environment for it: write the LD_LIBRARY_PATH value from LD_LIBRARY_PATH_ORIG.

An excerpt from the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#ld-library-path-libpath-considerations):

> **LD_LIBRARY_PATH / LIBPATH considerations**
>
> This environment variable is used to discover libraries, it is the library search path - on GNU/Linux and *BSD LD_LIBRARY_PATH is used, on AIX it is LIBPATH.
>
> If it exists, PyInstaller saves the original value to *_ORIG, then modifies the search path so that the bundled libraries are found first by the bundled code.
> But if your code executes a system program, you often do not want that this system program loads your bundled libraries (that are maybe not compatible with your system program) - it rather should load the correct libraries from the system locations like it usually does.
>
> Thus you need to restore the original path before creating the subprocess with the system program.

The code to replace the environment variable:

```
env = dict(os.environ) # make a copy of the environment
lp_key = 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' # for GNU/Linux and *BSD.
lp_orig = env.get(lp_key + '_ORIG')
if lp_orig is not None:
    env[lp_key] = lp_orig # restore the original, unmodified value
else:
    # This happens when LD_LIBRARY_PATH was not set.
    # Remove the env var as a last resort:
    env.pop(lp_key, None)
p = Popen(system_cmd, ..., env=env) # create the process
```